# Accessing current Knockout binding context

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

Take a look at the following code, with a focus on the embedded script:

```
<tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: foos, as: 'f' } -->
    <td>
        <!-- ko if: f.someCondition() -->
        <input id='picker' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#picker").kendoDatePicker({ 
                value: new Date(), 
                change: f.changeFunction });   <!---- note this line -->
        </script>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

See `f.changeFunction`?  I'm getting a JavaScript error that `f` is not defined.  How do I access the current binding context so I can attach the Kendo change handler to my current `foo`?  I've tried using a few of the [binding context variables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) but they aren't accessible outside of the binding expressions.  If I can't access the binding context in the embedded script, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using the kendo-knockout bindings?

http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/DatePicker.html

Comment: "Is there a reason you aren't using the kendo-knockout bindings? "  Um, I didn't know about them?

Comment: No problem, I thought that would work but just wanted to make sure you didn't need to setup the DatePickers like that for some reason :-)